# Gostaria de saber como eu pego o resultado de um comando no python que é executado no CMD e salvar em uma variável,

Tags: python, cmd

Esse programa pinga um *IP*, gostaria de pegar o resultado desse ping que é efetuado nesta linha

```
os.system ('ping -n 4 {} '.format(ip))
```

que abre o *CMD* e pinga o *IP*, e salvar em uma variável qualquer, para poder colocar em um arquivo `.txt` depois.

```
import PySimpleGUI
import os

class Tela : 

    def __init__ (self) :
        layout = [
            [PySimpleGUI.Text ('ip'),PySimpleGUI.Input(key='ip')],
            [PySimpleGUI.Button('enviar')]
        ]
        janela = PySimpleGUI.Window('Dados').layout(layout)
        self.button, self.values = janela.Read()

    def iniciar (self):
        print (self.values)
        ip = self.values ['ip']
        os.system ('ping -n 4 {} '.format(ip))
        return '' 


tela1 = Tela()
tela1.iniciar ()
```

Comment: Poderia esclarecer o que quer pegara e onde quer salvar?

Comment: Esse programa pinga um ip, gostaria de pegar o resultado desse ping que é efetuado nesta linha os.system ('ping -n 4 {} '.format(ip)), que abre o cmd e pinga o ip, e salvar em uma varíavel qualquer, para poder colocar em um arquivo .txt depois.

Comment: vocẽ pode simplesmente usar `os.popen()` em vez de `os.system` - e chamar o método `read()` no valor de retorno dele. A forma nova de fazer isso, com `subprocess.run` (ou pior, subprocess.Popen) que está na resposta complica demais alguns casos simples. Só ponha ali no `iniciar`: `return os.popen(f'ping -n 4 {ip}').read()` -  (ao contrário do "subprocess", as "f-strings" simplificam, não precisando colocar ".format" )

Answer (score 2):

Se quer obter o retorno no terminal de uma chamada de um processo de sistema use o módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) que permite gerar novos processos conectar-se aos pipes de entrada, saída e erro, e obter seus códigos de retorno.

```
import subprocess

google = 'www.google.com' 
ptSO = '151.101.129.69'
microsoft = '184.26.42.115'


def ping(site):
   #Abre um subprocesso ping usando a sintaxe Linux
   p = subprocess.run(['ping', '-c', '4', site], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   #Abre um subprocesso ping usando a sintaxe Windows
   #p = subprocess.run(['ping', '/n', '4', site], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

   stdout = p.stdout #captura stdout

   #Retorna o texto do terminal se hover erro retorna vazio
   return stdout.decode('UTF-8') if p.returncode == 0 else ''
   #No windows 
   #return stdout.decode('ISO-8859-1') if p.returncode == 0 else ''

print('aguarde...')
# Salva o retorno de alguns pings em uma lista
pings = [ping(google), ping(ptSO), ping(microsoft)]

print('salvando no arquivo...')
# Salva o retorno de alguns pings em um arquivo
with open("pings.txt", "w") as arquivo:
  for p in pings: 
    arquivo.write(f'{p}\n')

print('despejando no console...')
#imprime a lista contento a saída no terminal de alguns pings
for p in pings: print(f'{p}\n')
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/SuburbanThoroughLightweightprocess

Comment: Ocorre o seguinte erro
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 305: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: única coisa que desejo é pegar esse valor que sai e salvar em um .txt como se eu digitasse no cmd ping www.google.com > sarvar_arquivo.txt

Comment: por favor  - use o `subprocess.run` e re-escreva a resposta. Colocar "subprocess.Popen" como "substitudo padrão  de tudo" foi um dos maiores erros da evolução do Python em um período, já que transformou várias chamadas simplíssimas no módulo `os` e fez o megazord `subprocess.Popen` que é _muito_ mais complicado de usar. Para melhorar um pouco, fizeram o `subprocess.run` - que tem vários atributos padrão e simplifica os resultados.

Comment: E pode por um exemplo usando `os.popen(...).read()` também - querer complicar isso demais foi um erro, e obviamente não tem vantagens que compensem isso para casos simples.

Comment: Desculpa, não consegui entender.

Comment: Por que o comando os.system ('ping -n 4 {} '.format(ip) + ' > arquivo.txt') não funciona? Será que tem um caminho próximo desse?

Comment: @jsbueno não é querer complicar mas a própria documentação do módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) afirma que sua existência se deve a pretensão de substituir vários módulos e funções mais antigos listando `` e `os.system` e `os.spawn`. No [PEP 324](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/) afirma que a motivação desse módulo é substituir funções inadequadas para iniciar processos que possam significar um risco à segurança.

Comment: @GabrielAmorim se olhar bem o exemplo, vai ver que há uma linha comentada com a sintaxe do Windows: `#p = subprocess.run(['ping', '/n', '4', site], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` como parece estar usando o windows retire a linha anterior com a sintaxe Linux e use essa sintaxe.

Comment: @GabrielAmorim veja a edição que fiz na resposta.

Comment: O código que foi feito alterações da esse erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  , line 19, in <module>
    pings = [ping(google), ping(ptSO), ping(microsoft)]
  File "c:/Users/Gabriel Ramos Amorim/Documents/Programas/asda/as.py", line 15, in ping
    return stdout.decode('UTF-8') if p.returncode == 0 else ''
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 305: invalid start byte

Comment: @GabrielAmorim Vou testar no windows

Comment: Eu fiz no Windows, é o SO que eu uso. e deu esse erro

Comment: @GabrielAmorim Tenta isso: `return stdout.decode('ISO-8859-1') if p.returncode == 0 else ''`

Comment: @AugustoVasques - sim, por isso eu falei pra re-escrever usando `subprocess.run`  que é um meio termo.  E foi adimitido, depois de uns 6 ou 7 aos, que foi uma grande m. deixar a documentação do  `Popen` proeminente e o `.run` escondido - quando esse é muito mais simples e cobre quase todos os casos de uso.

Comment: Quanto as "questões de segurnaça", se referem a injeção de parâmetros para o shell, quando o que vai ser executado puder ser fornecido por usuários do programa, nao pelo programador. Não tem nem sentido em um script pra pegar saída do ping.

Comment: boa resp, mas pergunta dup de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448074/3635 ... pouquissimo esfor;o por parte do AP em revisar a pergunta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Consegui meu caro, muito obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielAmorim se a resposta o ajudou e não resta mais nenhuma dúvida considere a assinalar como correta clicando no simbolo ✔ ao lado.